# PyCharm stuck when trying to configure Docker interpreter via SSH to linux machine

Tags: docker, pycharm

I'm on PyCharm 2022.2 (Professional Edition) on Windows 10, working via SSH on a remote Linux machine.

I'm trying to configure a Docker interpreter and run my script inside a container.
Using the "Add Python Interpreter" wizard, I select "Docker" and configure a Docker server via SSH (and verify it connects successfully). The wizard recognizes the images on my Linux machine but when I click "OK" it gets stuck on "Getting Remote Interpreter Version" and never ends.
The only way to end this is to force close PyCharm.

Any ideas how to solve this?

[image]
[image]